# ffmpeg blend=screen makes background look green or foreground green

Tags: ffmpeg

When I apply a screen blend to the foreground asset (Pikachu) over the background asset (White circle on black background)
GIMP and Adobe Photoshop make the circle asset look white, and the background asset look RGB like this:-

[image]

which is how it should look.

However, if we take the input assets:-
[image]
and
[image]

and use this ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i circle_rgb_50.png -i pikachu_rgb.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]blend=screen" pikachu_screened_over_circle_rgb_just_blend.png
```

we get this:-
[image]

and if I reverse the blend so that the inputs to the blend function are the other way around, like this:-

```
ffmpeg -i circle_rgb_50.png -i pikachu_rgb.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=screen" pikachu_screened_over_circle_rgb_just_blend_other_way_around.png
```

we get this:-
[image]

Why doesn't FFMPEG do blending the same way as GIMP or Adobe Photoshop ?

Or is there another parameter I need to pass so that blends look as they should ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen` is the value of `all_mode` option of the `blend` filter. Correct your filter_complex:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]blend=all_mode=screen"
```